# Is it possible to bound type-variable not extend a class in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, ambiguous

I have these two methods:

```
public static int[] asArray(int... ints) {
    return ints;
}

public static <T extends Object> T[] asArray(T... ts) {
    return ts;
}
```

but it will cause "reference to `asArray` is ambiguous" error on calling like this:

```
asArray(1, 2, 3)
```

I know its because compiler have ambiguation between
calling first method with int type or second method with Integer type.

I want to know that can i bound type-parameter to **NOT extend** a special class like this:

```
public static <T not extends Number> T[] asArray(T... ts) {
    return ts;
}
```

That Number is super class of Integer in java.

Is it possible to bound type-variable not extend a class in java?

Comment: Note: `T extends Object` is the same as `T`.

Comment: Simple answer: no, this isn't possible.

Comment: you cannot say `not extend`, what you can do is to add a short circuit if at the beginning with `instanceof` your class and return something or throw an error.

Comment: BTW: in what sense is calling your method better than writing `= new int[]{...}` or `= new Integer[]{...}` respectively?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle its only for sense of code readability and better look!